# Several criterions in Dataframe.xs()

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a MultiIndex containing of two integers, and I want to select

```
where (level=0 in [0,1]) and (level=1 in [0,1])
```

(That is, I want `[[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]`)

How can I do that?

`.xs([0, 1], level=[0,1])` gives me `where level=0 in [0] and level=1 in [1]`, anything else I try that would make sense leads to KeyErrors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in 0.14.0 (releasing shortly), see [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#multiindexing-using-slicers)

rc1 is [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/releases)